# Поиск строки в текстовом файле на php

Tags: php

Имеется файл prepare_image.out в котором отражена информация вида:

```
copy "..\какой-то путь\1.txt" to "..\путь\сюда"
1 File(s) copied
copy "..\какой-то путь\2.txt" to "..\путь\сюда"
0 File(s) copied
```

Таких строк очень много и все отражают информацию о том какой файл куда копируется и информацию, скопировался файл или нет. 
Поиск я реализовала так:

```
$temp = fopen("prepare_image.err", "a+");
$log = 'prepare_image.out';
$arr_log = file($log);
$date = count($arr_log);

$needle = '0 File(s) copied';

for ($i = 0; $i <= $date; $i++) {
    $read = $arr[$date - $i];

    $pos = strripos($read, $needle);

    if ($pos === false) {
        echo "Ошибок, при копирование не обнаружено.";
        break;
    } else {
        echo "Warning! Обнаружены ошибки при копирование.";
        $string = substr($read, 0);
        fwrite($temp, $string  ."\n");
    }
}
```

Поиск организован с конца файла. 
И тут в prepare_image.err попадают только сами строки *0 File(s) copied*, а необходимо вывести строку **НАД** найденной *0 File(s) copied* 
То есть, выводить в другой файл строку `$date - ($i+1)` 
Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз, вам не подходит grep, не устоит усложнять свой мир. Регулярный выражения в данном случае, плохая идея, мы ищем статическую строку, а значит они нам не нужны. Если вам не нужно обрабатывать огромный файл, то используйте перебор. Эту задачу можно решить сотней способов, но зачем?

```
<?php

$result = explode("\n", file_get_contents("result.log"));
$errors = "";

foreach ($result as $key => $line) {
    if (trim($line) == '0 File(s) copied')
        $errors .= trim($result[$key - 1]) . PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents("result.err.log", $errors, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -B1 '0 File(s) copied' prepare_image.out | grep copy > prepare_image.err
```

это самый удобный способ.

grep - это один из самых необходимых инструментов программиста, утилита, которая служит именно для таких целей - поиск в файле по шаблону.

параметр -B1 говорит грепу возвращать одну строчку перед (Before) найденной (точно так же, как A  будет добавлять строки после)

повторный греп, запущенный через конвейерный оператор (|) вернет только строки с copy, без 0 File(s) copied. Кстати, конвейерный оператор хотят добавить в РНР.

весь вывод будет перенаправлен в prepare_image.err

Если же надо на пхп, то следует использовать preg_match_all()

Comment: эта утилита командной строки для windows актуальна? Может есть альтернатива или всё-таки придется через `preg_match_all()` делать?

Comment: из коробки под виндой ее нету, но найти и установить не проблема. Но я бы рекомендовал начинать осваивать линукс - эта система куда удобнее для разработчика.

Comment: а запустить FINDSTR повторно, аналогично вашему примеру с grep через конвейерный оператор (|) нельзя, да? Просто тоже можно найти строку: `FINDSTR /C:"0 File(s) copied" prepare_image.out`, но забрать предыдущую строку никак нельзя, да?

Comment: Через конвейер-то запустить можно, но вот предыдущие строки FINDSTR вроде не возвращает

Comment: А, это я фигню сказала. Это ничего не даст. Тут нет же параметра типа `-B1` =(

Comment: а почему стоит делать через preg_match_all? Ведь эта функция ищет шаблон в строке и пусть я найду строку целиком, но предыдущую строку с `copy` она не затронет и, соответственно, её не запишет в prepare_image.err Есть только параметр matches, но он, как я поняла, просто диктует правила, как выводить то, что нашли.

Comment: Слово "строка" имеет два значения. "Часть текста до перевода строки" и "текстовая переменная", которая, в свою очередь, может состоять из строк в первом значении. В данном случае мы говорим о втором значении. О всем тексте целиком. соответственно, читать файл надо будет не через file(), a file_get_contents()

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41442/discussion-between--and-).